# Flutter reverse animation complete listener

Tags: animation, flutter

I am trying to listen event for flutter reverse animation when it is completed but its not triggering for reverse just only for forward.

```
_animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.reverse &&
      status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    print("Reverse Animation is completed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also figured out another approach by myself.

```
  _animationController.reverse().then((void) {
      // Reverse animation completed
  });
```

Comment: hmm i am still seeing this fire at the start of the animation...

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `status == AnimationStatus.reverse && status == AnimationStatus.completed` is always false. `status` can't be equal to two values at the same time.

If you want to listen for when the animation / reverse animation is completed, use the following:

```
_animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    // Animation completed
  } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    // Reverse animation completed
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure about this? if i am playing in reverse from 1.0 the dismissed state doesn't fire